# Virtualbox stuck on purple loading screen

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtualbox

I have a Windows 10 machine with an AMD processor, and a GTX 1060.

This is the sequence of steps I perform on a fresh install of virtualbox:

1. Make a new virtual machine with 2048MB of ram for Linux 32 bit and select ubuntu
2. Make a new virtual hard disk VDI format with dynamically allocated size of 10gb.
3. Press the start button and insert the ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-i386.iso file into the disk rom
4. Ubuntu starts on the purple loading screen, I get a flow of orange dots over the white dots below the word Ubuntu 16.04 to indicate some level of loading
5. It stops with the first two dots left white and the last two dots are orange.
6. No progress is made from this point

I have installed everything fresh, and downloaded the ISO right from the website and made no alterations. My question is, how can I get ubuntu to work given my current scenario. I have also tried Mint and encounter similar but not identical issues. Below is a picture of my screen that its been stuck at for 10 mins.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Changed my UEFI bios settings to turn on CPU virtualisation and used a 64-bit OS and it fixed my problem.

Comment: You should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem, you have the correct iso file,my suggestion is to give more space to the guest OS and if it does not again work to reinstall the virtual box and try again,maybe is 10 gb too little space.
Good luck.

Comment: Although it turned out that in this case, 10 GB was largely sufficient, and hardware virtualisation was the issue, it is worth saying that Ubuntu 18 will procure a Purple Screen Of Death (PSOD) if you're trying to install it on a 2GB virtual disk on Oracle VM Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your bios settings have virtualization (sometimes called VT-x) enabled, *AND* your host windows settings have 'Hyper-V' disabled in "Turn Windows Features On or Off" dialog.